# How to translate this comment from doxygen to javadoc?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, doxygen

How to translate this comment from doxygen to javadoc?

```
/// <typeparam name="SolutionType">the custom solution data type, derived from <see cref="Solution{InputDataType}">Solution</see></typeparam>
```

Instead of typeparam I can use @param in javadoc.
But I am not sure how to translate the see tag?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Your comment does not look like a Doxygen comment.  Doxygen comment annotation is largely a superset of Javadoc, and I'd expect to see:

```
/// @param SolutionType The custom solution data type, derived from Solution.
```

Which would work with both Doxygen and Javadoc.  Doxygen automatically make a link on 'Solution' if it is a class name within the currently processed set (or in a tag file specified in the config).  I don't know if Javadoc will do this - its been a long time since I bothered with JavaDoc even in Java code.